# Web Services and static methods

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-services, design-patterns

I am using ASP.NET Web Services such as:

```
[WebMethod]
public void DeleteColumn(long columnId)
{
    Column.DeleteColumn(columnId);
}
```

The problem is that sudh programming requires many static methods.
For example, if I would like to do things without static methods, I would have to do something like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public void DeleteColumn(Column c)
{
    c.DeleteColumn();
}
```

This implementation have two problems in my opinion:

1. I have to create an empty constructor for Column class.
2. I have to pass from the client whole object instead of one parameter. In the time of using this web service I can't know whice members the client should fill in order to perform the method (delete in this case).

I believe there are many more problems with the last approach I've wrote but I know also that static methods are not the best for Object Oriented Programming.
What do you think? how should I implement webservices?
Is there any place with design patterns for such problems or for web developers?

Comment: Thanks for the advise but most of my questions doesn't have an answer.

Comment: @Naor: sometimes you just have to bite the bullet and select the closest answer. Otherwise, people won't want to invest the time in helping you. Luckily, *I* don't care. :)

Comment: @Naor: Most of your questions have multiple answers. If they aren't acceptable answers, it might indicate that the questions themselves need work.

Comment: BTW, these methods aren't "static". You may mean "stateless", but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Naor, what kinds of problems do you think static methods are causing? (Or what kind of benefits do you expect to gain from moving to a more object-oriented approach?)

Comment: @Jeff Sternal: I cannot force implementation of delete method in child class when the delete is static - for example.
@MusiGenesis: I think I ment static: public static void DeleteColumn"

Comment: @MusiGenesis: He's saying the Column.DeleteColumn method is static. @Jeff Sternal, @Shadow Wizard: Static implementations of business logic force your code to be tightly coupled to specific implementations, which breaks the Dependency Inversion Principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) of SOLID programming practices.

Comment: @All: If i'll mark reply as an answer - a new user with relevant answer may not refer to my post.

Answer (score 4):

Why not initialise your `Column` object from the Id you're passing in?

```
[WebMethod]
public void DeleteColumn(long columnId)
{
    Column c = new Column(columnId);
    c.DeleteColumn();
}
```

I'm guessing a little here, but is one of the reasons you're looking to avoid `static` methods is so that they're easier to test? If that's the case, you could delegate the creation of your `Column` object to some other factory object, to facilitate injecting a fake column for testing purposes.

```
[WebMethod]
public void DeleteColumn(long columnId)
{
    IColumn c = ColumnFactory.CreateColumn(columnId);
    c.DeleteColumn();   // Could be any object that implements IColumn
}
```

Comment: @razlebe: I want to avoid static in order to use inheritance properly. Child classes cannot override static methods. The problem I have using your solution is that one can use Column c = new Column(columnId); and think that c is fully instanciated and it has all members filled from the datasource (for example), where actually it filled only columnId.

Comment: @Naor Isn't that the point, though? To avoid passing, as you say in your question, "a whole object", you instead pass the column id around. Armed with that column Id, you execute whatever code is necessary to properly instantiate a Column object, whether that be the Column constructor or some other code (e.g. a factory or builder object of some description).

Comment: @razlebe: But in order to perform delete I only need the columnId! I do not need to load and build the whole object from the database.

Comment: @Naor Then it's not a Column object you want - it's your database connection/query object, and a SQL statement.

Comment: @razlebe: as the access layer I have class with static functions that call stored procedures. I don't really have well designed access layer. I can't use the access layer in the webservices since I skip the buisiness layer.

Comment: @Naor Well, you can't have it both ways. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use dependency injection instead. Most DI frameworks have plugins available that make it so you can just change the .svc file to specify a host factory. Then your code could look more like this.

```
private IColumnRepository _columnRepository;
public MyWebService(IColumnRepository columnRepository)
{
    _columnRepository = columnRepository;
}
[WebMethod]
public void DeleteColumn(long columnId)
{
    _columnRepository.DeleteColumn(columnId);
}
```

#### Edit

Sorry, I didn't realize this was ASMX. If you have the option, you ought to switch to WCF. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552872%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

> This topic is specific to a legacy technology. XML Web services and XML Web service clients should now be created using Windows Communication Foundation (WCF).

But even if you're stuck with ASMX, Dependency Injection is a viable option. For example, using Ninject, you could do something like this:

```
[Inject]
public IColumnRepository ColumnRepository {get;set;}
public MyWebService()
{
    Injection.Kernel.Inject(this);
}
[WebMethod]
public void DeleteColumn(long columnId)
{
    _columnRepository.DeleteColumn(columnId);
}
```

It ties you to the injection kernel a little more tightly, but you still get many of the advantages of dependency injection.

Comment: Naor is using asmx web services and not WCF.  Just curious if most DI frameworks support asmx?  I would guess they would have to replace the `WebServiceHandlerFactory` with their own handler?

Comment: @Tuzo: Thanks for pointing that out. I'm not finding any good documentation on implementing constructor injection with ASMX. I'm guessing it's like WebForms, and doesn't lend itself to IoC very well. However, you can still do Property injection. See my edit.